# javascript and css response return 404 in merb application

Tags: ruby, thin, unicorn, merb, rackup

I'm trying to setup a merb application now trying to start the merb as normal rack

application using either by thin , unicorn or plainly using rackup the html content are

returned but the javascript and css response is returning 404

```
~ No routes match the request: /javascripts/jquery.highlight.js - (Merb::ControllerExceptions::NotFound)
```

This is what it state for each assets try to access

now start the merb using ./bin/merb just work like all javascript and css are render with

200 but I looking to deploy the application using unicorn hence want to avoid the 404 errors

Comment: FYI all the javascript and stylesheet returning `404` are actually present in public directory